# Navigating to a nested xib

Tags: iphone, view, navigation, nested

I have a menu view (Menu.xib) that has several options. One of the options is 'Games' which when touched goes to a list of games (GamesList.xib). On this view there is an '+' button to add a new game (AddGame.xib).

What I would like to do is from the menu, click Add Game option which will load GamesList and then AddGame. So when I have added the game it goes back to the GamesList not the menu.

I have tried to push a new view controller (the AddGame controller) from the viewWillAppear message of the GamesList controller. But this causes the view navigation to go wrong.

There must be a simple solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested I have my answer. And as I suspected is so simple I want to cry.

The solution is simply to push the view controllers one after the other with only the last push set animated:YES

Then you are shown the last view in the stack and you can navigate back as you would normally.

Having said that, I still dont understand why it wont work if the first view loads which auotloads the second view which the auto loads the third view etc. Oh well!!